# docker container consume more space in host than in container

Tags: docker, volume

I have a container (image: drakkan/sftpgo),  after running this container, the host disk consumption keep growing fast ,  the df -h command shows nearly 5G consumed (The /var/lib/docker is a softlink to /datadrive folder ),  it grows 2G each week.

[image]

But it's very weird, when I enter docker container and execute du command to check the folder size, I find it actually do not consume much.  The docker system df command also shows that only 200 Mb is consumed by this container.

[image]

Anyone knows that why the host disk keeps growing for container folder , but the container actually does not consume that much?

Comment: As you've described this, it isn't really a programming question; do you have a [mcve] demonstrating this file-usage pattern?  Note that storing text content as image files can be hard to read and requires a lot more space; if your image attachments are actually terminal output, it'd be a good idea to [edit] the question and replace the images with plain text instead.